# Ubuntu 18.04 does not detect HDMI audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, monitor

My ubuntu 18.04 distribution isn't detecting my monitor's HDMI audio.

The output from `uname -a` is

```
Linux sunrise 4.15.0-51-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 15 14:27:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output from `lsb_release -a` is

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I look at sound settings I only see the following
[image]

I'm expecting to see something with `hdmi` but nothing shows up. I'm however able to use the monitor by having another old VGA monitor connected to the VGA port during boot time and subsequently having it mirror displays. Could someone help out here and give me some pointers on what I need to do to fix this please?

I've already tried `pulseaudio -k` followed by `sudo alsa force-reload` and rebooting. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there may be issues with Nvidia driver 415 and higher. Try using a 410 or lower driver for the time being. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044547/linux/audio-problems-with-the-415-18-drivers/4

Answer (score 0):

HDMI/DP output shows up now after reverting to X.Org drivers on 19.04.

Based on Chad's response and the linked thread, I reverted the Nvidia proprietary 415-18 drivers to the Nouveau display driver (no version listed) and rebooted.

This is rather unfortunate since I switched to the proprietary drivers due to lock screen issues where I couldn't recover the secondary display. Hopefully that bug has been ironed out!